# Azure kubernetes deployment error - 0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match node selector

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I am working on deploying one of my application to the Azure Kubernetes.
I have ACR and AKS configured, I am trying the deployment through azure CLI.

Here is the kubernetes deployment file content

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pocaksimage1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pocaksimage1
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": windows
      containers:
      - name: pocaksimage1
        image: pocaksimage1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
          name: pocaksimage1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pocaksimage1
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6379
  selector:
    app: pocaksimage1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pocaksimage1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  minReadySeconds: 5 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pocaksimage1
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": windows
      containers:
      - name: pocaksimage1
        image: repo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 250m
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
        env:
        - name: PRE_PROD
          value: "pocaksimage1"
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: pocsecret
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pocaksimage1-front
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: pocaksimage1-front
```

The error I am getting is "0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match node selector."

Please help me to get this resolved.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the issue is with the fact AKS doesnt yet support windows nodes, so you dont really have windows nodes. You can create AKS with windows nodes, but its in preview at this point in time.

https://github.com/Azure/AKS/blob/master/previews.md#windows

Comment: Is there any alternative to achieve this? I want to run windows based docker containers/nodes onto AKS.

Comment: you can register for preview or use virtual nodes